# How to save mongoose data after PATCH?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, feathersjs

My Feathers.js app has a questionnaire and I'm trying to save the results for each input. Here is my client-side code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/answer",
  type: "PATCH",
  data: newAnswer,
  success: function () {
    console.log("Answer submitted!");
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("Error submitting answer.");
  }
});
```

And here is my server-side code:

```
app.patch("/answer", (req, res) => {
  users.patch(user[0]._id, req.body);
});
```

Currently, only the last input is saved. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is my schema

```
answers: {
  yourOrganization: {
    page1: {
      idOfParameterInClient: response
    }
  }
}
```

The `idOfParameterInClient` and the `response` are dynamic. In `page1`, there are a number of key/value pairs. How do I keep them?

Comment: What you are doing is merge the user object with the `newAnswer` object. Any property in the `newAnswer` object will overwrite the same property in the user object.

Comment: @Daff I've added more clarification to my question/issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`patch` does not do a recursive merge (neither will MongoDB). If that is what you are looking for you will have to do it yourself e.g. using the [deepmerge package](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/deepmerge):

```
const merge = require('deepmerge');

app.patch("/answer", (req, res) => {
  const id = user[0]._id;

  users.get(id).then(user => {
    const mergedUser = merge(user.toObject(), req.body);

    users.patch(id, mergedUser);
  });

});
```

Comment: I keep trying this and variations of this but nothing shows up in mongoose. Looking at `mergedUser` in the console is weird too because I just see functions as well as the data.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you are using Mongoose with feathers-mongoose before v4.0.0 you have to call `.toObject` first

Comment: I didn't realize I was still using outdated modules! Thanks for the tip. I'm going to keep what I did since it worked as is but I'll accept your response as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Daff put me on the right track. In the end, `object-patch` allowed me to do recursive merges. Here is my code:

```
const patch = require("object-patch");

app.patch("/answer", (req, res) => {
  const id = user[0]._id;

  users.get(id).then(user => {
    patch(user, req.body);
    users.update(user._id, user);
  });
});
```